# How to change parameters in Contiki 2.7 simulation?

Tags: simulator, contiki

I started learning on Contiki OS. I am trying to analyze few parameters like energy efficiency, latency, delivery ratio etc with different deployment scenarios. First I should change some parameter like:

1. Channel check rate to 16/s (I use rpl-sink)
2. RPL mode of operation to NO_DOWNWARD_ROUTE
3. Send interval to 5s
4. UDP application packet size to 100 Bytes

Could you please  tell me how to change these parameter in  Contiki 2.7?

Comment: Well have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answers for reference:

> Channel check rate to 16/s (I use rpl-sink)

```
#undef  NETSTACK_RDC_CHANNEL_CHECK_RATE
#define NETSTACK_RDC_CHANNEL_CHECK_RATE 16
```

> RPL mode of operation to NO_DOWNWARD_ROUTE

It's called non-storing mode. To enable it:

`#define RPL_CONF_WITH_NON_STORING 1`

> Send interval to 5s

Depends on the application; there is no standard name for this parameter. If we're talking about `ipv6/rpl-collect/`, you should `#define PERIOD 5` in `project-conf.h`.

> UDP application packet size to 100 Bytes

The payload is constructed in `udp-sender.c`:

```
uip_udp_packet_sendto(client_conn, &msg, sizeof(msg),
                      &server_ipaddr, UIP_HTONS(UDP_SERVER_PORT));
```

So in order to change the payload size, you need to change the  size of the locally-defined anonymous `struct` variable called `msg`. You can add some dummy fields to it, for example.

```
struct {
  uint8_t seqno;
  uint8_t for_alignment;
  struct collect_view_data_msg msg;
  char dummy[100 - 2 - sizeof(struct collect_view_data_msg)];
} msg;
```

Comment: thanks for answer. how can I see the size of packet that send in simulation, and how I can set the Start delay to 100 s

Comment: 1. Find some documentation about Contiki and Cooja. 2. Read it and experiment. 3. If you need further clarification, as a new question here about a single problem and show the research you have already done.